# Drawing random number iterating over list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list

```py
[1,2,4]
```

I define the maximum value `z_max = 4` and `dz = 0.5`, so `k = z_max/dz = 8`. A diagram to show the intervals below

[image]

So essentially my pseudo code looks like this:

1. In the first interval `(0,1)` draw a random number `r1`
2. In the second interval `(1,2)` draw a new random number `r2`
3. In the third interval `(2,4)` draw a new random number `r3`
4. Create a list with `k` elements `[r1,r1,r2,r2,r3,r3,r3,r3]`

I think you must start by computing the intervals in the list

```py
list1 = [1,2,4]
list1_diff = np.diff(list1)
#Append first interval missed
print(np.insert(list1_diff,0,1))
```

```sh
[1,1,2]
```

so this list is the interval lengths in the list. I now need to divide each element in the list by `dz` to find how many times (k times) I should draw and repeat a random number. How can I use a python list to then produce

```py
[r1,r1,r2,r2,r3,r3,r3,r3]
```

where `r1`,`r2` and `r3` are `N(0,1)` random numbers? I would like pointing in the right direction...I am pretty stuck.

Comment: you have posted this question before

Comment: I reworded it and deleted the old one

Comment: I'm trying to understand "draw and repeat". For each interval, do we draw once and repeat k times or draw k times? Also - does the first interval always start at 0?

Answer (score 0):

So this is my understanding of your problem:

- You are being given a list of integers not smaller than 1 in `list1`
- You have information on a step size `dz`
- I assume that the difference between neighboring integers in `list1` devided by `dz` returns and integer `size_diff`
- this `size_diff` is the number of times you want to see one random number sampled from a normal distribution in your `result_list`

```
import numpy as np

dz = .5
list1 = [1, 2, 4]
result_list = []

# insert 0 for first interval
list1.insert(0, 0)

for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    start = list1[i]
    end = list1[i+1]
    diff = end - start
    size_diff = int(diff / dz)
    random_nr = np.random.normal(0, 1)
    result_list.extend([random_nr]*size_diff)

print(result_list)
```

Use at your own risk, but I hope this is a useful hint for you!
Edit: Please accept the answer. It appears correct and I've been answer-blocked!